# using setTimeout to render component in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to render a component from my screen after 3 seconds, this is due to some time delay when the user changes accounts, I need those 3 seconds so the data can be exactly what the user wants. Before rendering that piece of component, I wanted to load a container with loading in the center. I have inserted the data into the component but I get an error from `component exception`:
[image]

This is how I'm rendering the data:

```
export function Dashboard({ drawerAnimationStyle}: any) {
    const navigation: any = useNavigation();
    const { firebaseFunctions } = useAuth();

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState<DataListProps[]>([]);
    const [higlightData, setHighlightData] = useState<HighlightDataProps>({} as HighlightDataProps);
    const theme = useTheme();

    async function loadTransaction(): Promise<any> {
        const data = await firebaseFunctions.loadTransaction();

        setTransactions(data.transactionsFormatted);

        setHighlightData(data.higlightData);

        setIsLoading(false);

    }

    useEffect(() => {   
        loadTransaction();
    }, [transactions]);

    return (
        <Animated.View style={{ flex: 1, ...drawerAnimationStyle}}>         
            <Container>
                {
                    isLoading ? 
                    <LoadingContainer>
                        <ActivityIndicator color={theme.colors.blue} size='large'/>
                    </LoadingContainer>
                    :
                    <>
                        <Header>                            
                            <DrawerContainer onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
                                <Icon name="menu" />
                            </DrawerContainer>
                            <HighLightCards>
                                <HighLightCard type="up" title="Income" amount={higlightData.entries.amount} lastTransaction={higlightData.entries.lastTransaction}/>
                                <HighLightCard type="down"title="Outcome" amount={higlightData.outcome.amount}lastTransaction={higlightData.outcome.lastTransaction}/>
                                <HighLightCard type="total" title="Total" amount={higlightData.total.amount} lastTransaction={higlightData.total.lastTransaction}/>
                            </HighLightCards>
                        </Header>                       

                        {
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                return (
                                    <Transactions>
                                        <Title>Transactions</Title>
                                        {
                                            transactions.length <= 0 ?
                                            <NoTransaction>
                                                <LottieView 
                                                    source={NoTransactionLottie}
                                                    style={{
                                                        width: 100,
                                                        height: 100,                                                                    
                                                    }}
                                                    autoPlay
                                                    loop
                                                    resizeMode='contain'
                                                />
                                            </NoTransaction>
                                            :
                                            <TransactionsList
                                                data={transactions}                     
                                                keyExtractor={(item: { id: any }) => item.id}
                                                renderItem={({ item }: any) => <TransactionCard  data={item}/>}
                                            />
                                        }
                                    </Transactions>
                                );
                            }, 3000)
                        }
                    </>
                }
            </Container>
        </Animated.View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to introduce a race condition.

Instead, listen for your async data to be ready and set the loading flag appropriately.

```
useEffect(() => {   
  // Or however you decide to check if your state is set
  if (transactions.length && Object.keys(higlightData).length) setLoading(false);
}, [transactions, higlightData]);

// then

{loading ? <Loading /> : <StuffThatUsesTransactionsAndHighlightData />}
```

Also, if loading is not set in any other place, then this is derived state and should be simplified to

```
const loading = transactions.length && Object.keys(higlightData).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` is not valid inside the function return because it doesn't have any implicit return.  This is also an anti-pattern in that you will display after 3 seconds whether you have data or not.  You should show data if you have it, and indicate loading (or failure) if you don't.

You already have a loading state in the indicator, so if you can't trust that, you should focus on fixing that instead of trying to delay rendering.

If you absolutely must delay rendering for some reason, don't use `setTimeout` in the return, use it in the function body.  e.g.

```js
...
const [delayComplete, setDelayComplete] = useState(false);
...

useEffect(() => {
  if (isLoading || delayComplete) return;

  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    setDelayComplete(true)
  }, 3000);

  return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
}, [isLoading, delayComplete, setDelayComplete]);

// in return
  { delayComplete ? (...): (...) }
```

Comment: Where should I insert the `loadTransaction()`?

Comment: It's fine where you have it in the `useEffect` hook.

Answer (score 1):

try this for refresh the screen after 3 sec,

const [refreshData, setRefreshData] = useState(false);

```
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    refreshData ? setRefreshData(false) : setRefreshData(true);
  }, 3000);




  useEffect(() => {
  //..
   }, [refreshData]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's introduce small timeout hooks optimized for React component render cycles.

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function useTimeout(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      const id = setTimeout(tick, delay);
      return () => clearTimeout(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}

export default useTimeout;
```

Then Refactor code as below

```js
//Top-evel import 
import useTimeout from './useTimeout'

export function Dashboard({ drawerAnimationStyle }: any) {
  const navigation: any = useNavigation();
  const { firebaseFunctions } = useAuth();

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  // Delay transaction component rendering  for 3 seconds
  const [hasDelayed, setDelayed] = useState(false);

  const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState < DataListProps > [];
  const [higlightData, setHighlightData] = useState < HighlightDataProps > {};
  const theme = useTheme();

  async function loadTransaction(): Promise<any> {
    const data = await firebaseFunctions.loadTransaction();

    setTransactions(data.transactionsFormatted);

    setHighlightData(data.higlightData);

    setIsLoading(false);
  }

// Delay transaction components render for 3 seconds
  useTimeout() => {
    setDelayed(true);
  }, 3000);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadTransaction();
  }, [transactions]);

  return (
    <Animated.View style={{ flex: 1, ...drawerAnimationStyle }}>
      <Container>
        {isLoading ? (
          <LoadingContainer>
            <ActivityIndicator color={theme.colors.blue} size="large" />
          </LoadingContainer>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Header>
              <DrawerContainer onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
                <Icon name="menu" />
              </DrawerContainer>
              <HighLightCards>
                <HighLightCard
                  type="up"
                  title="Income"
                  amount={higlightData.entries.amount}
                  lastTransaction={higlightData.entries.lastTransaction}
                />
                <HighLightCard
                  type="down"
                  title="Outcome"
                  amount={higlightData.outcome.amount}
                  lastTransaction={higlightData.outcome.lastTransaction}
                />
                <HighLightCard
                  type="total"
                  title="Total"
                  amount={higlightData.total.amount}
                  lastTransaction={higlightData.total.lastTransaction}
                />
              </HighLightCards>
            </Header>

            {hasDelayed && (
              <Transactions>
                <Title>Transactions</Title>
                {transactions.length <= 0 ? (
                  <NoTransaction>
                    <LottieView
                      source={NoTransactionLottie}
                      style={{
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                      }}
                      autoPlay
                      loop
                      resizeMode="contain"
                    />
                  </NoTransaction>
                ) : (
                  <TransactionsList
                    data={transactions}
                    keyExtractor={(item: { id: any }) => item.id}
                    renderItem={({ item }: any) => (
                      <TransactionCard data={item} />
                    )}
                  />
                )}
              </Transactions>
            )}
          </>
        )}
      </Container>
    </Animated.View>
  );
}
```